# Equally spread cells within rows that have different column numbers

Tags: tables, tabularx

I tried to create something like this using tabular and tabularx but just can't get the cells to equally spread out. I would be very grateful for a short working example! Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}` etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. If no hero takes the challenge we might have to close your question.

Comment: On a given row, do columns have to be a fixed width, or is it the gap around the cell text that should be spread evenly to all cells in that row?

Comment: You might want to have a look at the multicolumn command.

Answer (score 1):

Since there was no MWE included yet, the following code might serve as a starting point:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|l|c||p{9cm}|}
\hhline{--||-}
\rowcolor{gray}\multicolumn{2}{|c||}{\textcolor{white}{aaaaa}} & \textcolor{white}{bbbbb}\\
\hhline{==::=}
1 & some text & \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}X|X|X|X@{}} a & b & \cellcolor{lightgray}c & d\end{tabularx}\\
\hhline{--||-}
2 & text & \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}X|X|X@{}} a & b & c \end{tabularx}\\
\hhline{--||-}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```